# File operation failed with New-PSSession

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I'm loading a json file that contains a list of computer names and each of them contains a list of files I need to operate on. For this example, I'm just displaying the file sizes.

But I'm getting file not found errors. I think it's because `new-pssession` is not activated or opened. I confirmed the file does exist on the remote computers. Is there something I need to do to "activate/open" the session after `new-pssession`?

```
$cred = Get-Credential -UserName admin -Message "Enter Password" 
$computers = Get-Content "sample.json" | ConvertFrom-Json    
foreach($computer in $computers){
    $s = new-pssession -ComputerName $computer.computer -Credential $cred
    foreach($file in $computer.files){        
        write-host $file has (get-item $file).length "bytes"
    }
    remove-pssession $s 
}
```

json file

```
[
    {
        "computer": "machine1",
        "files": [
            "c:\\temp\\done.png",
            "c:\\temp\\Permissions.xlsx"
        ]
    },
    {
        "computer": "machine2",
        "files": [
            "c:\\software\\TortoiseSVN.msi",
            "c:\\software\\TortoiseSVN.txt"
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) points out in his helpful comment, [`New-PSSession`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-pssession?view=powershell-7.2) will only establish the persistent connection with the remote hosts, however if you need to execute code on them you would need to use [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command).

I have removed `New-PSSession` for this example as there is no need for it in this case, but note, when using a *PSSession*, you would be using the `-Session` parameter instead of `-ComputerName`.

```sh
$cred = Get-Credential -UserName admin -Message "Enter Password" 
$computers = Get-Content "sample.json" | ConvertFrom-Json
foreach($computer in $computers)
{
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer.computer {
        $computer = $using:computer
        foreach($file in $computer.files)
        {
            Write-Host "$file has $((Get-Item $file).Length) bytes"
        }
    } -Credential $cred 
}
```

Since `Invoke-Command` allows parallel execution of *script blocks* on remote hosts, the same can be done with your code, however it would be a bit more complex. `$computers` would be passed to each remote session and each host would need to figure out which `object` of the `object[]` has to run:

```sh
$cred = Get-Credential -UserName admin -Message "Enter Password" 
$computers = Get-Content "sample.json" | ConvertFrom-Json
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computers.computer {
    $computers = $using:computers
    $files = $computers.Where({ $_.computer -eq $env:ComputerName }).files
    foreach($file in $files)
    {
        Write-Host "$file has $((Get-Item $file).Length) bytes"
    }
} -Credential $cred
```

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks for pointing that out. In this use case, `Invoke-Command` will do the work. I also looked up `$using` since it looks unnecessary and found out it's needed to password local variables to remote script.